# Apache adds character to Request URI that isnt actually there causing false rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that is reachable under 2 domains. If you visit the website under my2domain.eu (example) you should always be redirected to a specific page. For that I have the following redirect in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my2domain\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/projects/my2domain.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.my2domain.eu/en/projects/my2domain [L,R=307]
```

If you visit https://www.my2domain.eu/en/projects/my2domain you end in an infinite loop though, you will always get redirected to https://www.my2domain.eu/en/projects/my2domain.

After trying for hours I contacted my server provider which found out that Apache, when visiting https://www.my2domain.eu/en/projects/my2domain, finds the following input:

```
[rewrite:trace4] ... ... mod_rewrite.c(480) ... - - [www.my2domain.eu/sid#23544d0][rid#7f7c08006a60/initial] [perdir
/home/dlrxxdcg/www.my1domain.eu] RewriteCond:
input='/xen/projects/my2domain.eu' pattern='!^/en/projects/my2domain.eu.*$' [NC] =>
matched
```

Notice the **/xen/** instead of /en/ input altough we visit https://www.my2domain.eu/en/projects/my2domain and not https://www.my2domain.eu/xen/projects/my2domain

Is this a known phenomenon? Any ideas why Apache behaves like this?

This also happens in a completely blank htaccess with only these rules.

Comment: Try removing the leading `/`, so `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^en/projects/my2domain.*$ [NC]` (if it helps, I will add an answer with more explanation)

Comment: @DusanBajic thanks but it doesnt help. Even if I consider any characters before `en` it always falsily matches: `!(.*)?en/projects/my2domain.*$`

Comment: @DusanBajic That makes no sense, the %{REQUEST_URI} always has an _absolute_ path, unlike the actual subject the rule's pattern gets applied against when implementing rules in distributed configuration files. So the pattern you suggest can never match.