# How do clean urls stay in your adress bar when requests are redirected to index.php?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

In many CMS you will find htaccess rewrites like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In my understanding, when you visit domain.com/foobar, this rule applies (since the folder/file foobar doesnt exist) and the CMS, like Drupal, will look up if an alias for the current request exists and spit out the respective content.

How is it achieved that the url in your browser stays domain.com/foobar and not domain.com/index.php? Does that happen in Apache or PHP?

Bonus level: in addition to that, [I asked a different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68015771/apache-adds-character-to-request-uri-that-isnt-actually-there-causing-false-rewr). Could this have anything to do with redirects to index.php?

Comment: `How is it achieved that the url in your browser stays domain.com/foobar and not domain.com/index.php`: It is due to this rule that doesn't redirect to *target* but silently rewrites to given *target*. So client (browser) doesn't know that rewrite has occurred.

Comment: @anubhava Ah, so the rewrite is something internal and not a redirect, makes sense.

Comment: It is not the CMS which is responsible for this, actually the CMS does not really know about rewriting. It is the process that handles the incoming request and the reply that is generated by the CMS: the http server which is resposible on protocol level. So here the apache http server. What is often called a ".htaccess file" actually is a "distributed configuration file". It configures the behavior of the http server. Such configuration is usually done at a central place (for very good reasons). But there are exceptions where this has to be done in a decentralized way, in a ".htaccess file".

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your input but that was not the question at all

Comment: Sorry, I just reacted to your phrasing "and the CMS, like Drupal, will look up if an alias for the current request exists". To me this appeared to indicate that you had the impression that your application (CMS) logic evaluates those rules, which simply is not the case. I tried to fix this impression. Even better if that was a missunderstanding.